# Why are there unexpected dips in publish and consumer ack in a rabbitmq queue?

Tags: performance, rabbitmq, message-queue, publish-subscribe

here is the screenshot for the queued messages and message rate graphs
[queue details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2fx9.png)

I have tried increasing the consumers for the queue and message publish rate is 150 but still there are dips.

Comment: What about checking producer/consumer logs for errors in those intervals?

Answer (score 0):

An hour scale graph is not very helpful, keep in mind that statistics are only updated every 5 seconds, a single blip to zero can be caused by ack blocking while waiting for a persistent queue to be batched to disk which happens at 10 hertz. If your operation takes less than 100 ms consider using batching and sizing your prefetch accordingly for maximum throughput.